# Unable to hide sh step on jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I am unable to hide the execution of an sh step on my jenkins pipeline on the Blue Ocean view, my `Jenkinsfile` looks like this:

```
sh '#!/bin/sh -e\n' + "curl -s -u..."
```

I have tried multiple variants and cannot get it to work, even tho have made this worked before. :/ Any suggestions of what might be wrong might be appreciated

[image: Cannot hide]

P.S: I know I can/should use the Credentials plugin to hide my passwords just hadn't done it just yet

Comment: I'm having the same problem.
Also tried that `bin/sh -e` approach... that at least hides the spam you don't want to see. But it still shows up in BlueOcean.

Unfortunately, I don't think this will ever be possible to hide as Jenkins devs have this inane philosophy that they know better than their users what their users should or shouldn't want to do.

Comment: Things like this make you consider to switch to CircleCI or Github Actions.
They seem to have stopped developing on the product long time ago, same shitty interface, same bugs, same restrictions no matter how long you wait

Comment: @Zucca, I opened ticket to jenkins https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-68062 and they provided some workarounds.